# Getting a div to float outside of its parent, without using position:absolute

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where I have an outer `div` with `padding`, and inside it a bunch of inner `div`s. However, I want certain inner divs to essentially "not be affected by the `padding`" of the outer `div`. I want them to visibly expand the whole width of the outer `div`.

To give a concrete scenario, what I'd want is the blue `div`s below to be touching up against the black-lined walls on the left and right, while keeping their inner text left-aligned with that of the red `div`s. **Unfortunately, though, one constraint is that I need to keep the padding of the outer div, due to the fact that I'm working with a global stylesheet and many subpages of my site will be wrecked if I change the padding of the outer div**. I need to do this in a reliable fashion since it will be reused several times.

```css
div.outer {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
}
div.inner {
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
}
div.inner.expand {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"><p>Here's some content</p></div>
  <div class="inner"><p>Here's some more content</p></div>
  <div class="inner"><p>Here's some more content</p></div>
  <div class="inner expand"><p>Here's some more content</p></div>
  <div class="inner"><p>Here's some more content</p>   </div> 
  <div class="inner expand"><p>Here's some more content</p>   </div> 
</div>
```

Fiddle me, guys: http://jsfiddle.net/2whug2af/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the padding is `20px` wide, you can use a negative margin to counteract it:

```css
div.inner.expand {
    margin: 0 -20px;
}
```

```css
div.outer {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
}
div.inner {
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
}
div.inner.expand {
  background: blue;
  margin: 0 -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"><p>Here's some content</p></div>
  <div class="inner"><p>Here's some more content</p></div>
  <div class="inner"><p>Here's some more content</p></div>
  <div class="inner expand"><p>Here's some more content</p></div>
  <div class="inner"><p>Here's some more content</p>   </div> 
  <div class="inner expand"><p>Here's some more content</p>   </div> 
</div>
```